# Vue 3 how to pass props value to child component programmatic ( NOT IN PARENT TEMPLATE )

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Is it possible to passing value to child component as prop not from parent template
example let say

```
//ChildComponent
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
 componentId:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
 },
})
</script>
```

Parent component

```
//Parent component
<script setup lang="ts">
 import ChildComponet from './ChildComponet.vue'

//todo passing a child prop componentId value here not in template
</script>

<template>
  <-- not here -->
</template>
```

Comment: Have you read about the provide, inject option? This is to avoid having to pass props all the way down to grandchildren components but it works one level deep as well

Comment: Needs a proper example

Comment: @dbzx10299 thanks works as expected by use provide and inject..